# How to Remove single Inverted comma from array in python?

Tags: python, django

I have the following array:

```
a =['1','2']
```

I want to convert this array into the below format :

```
a=[1,2]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: from string to int?

Comment: I think you'll need to read up on the various data types in Python. Your problem isn't "removing inverted commas", it's "how to convert a list of strings into a list of integers".

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that. You change each element of `a` (which are strings) in an integer.

```
a=[int(x) for x in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

This single inverted comma you are talking about is the difference between str and int. This is pretty basic python stuff.

A string is a characters, displayed with the inverted comma's around it. 'Hello' is a string, but '1' can be a string too.

In you case ['1','2'] is a list of strings, and [1,2] is a list of numbers.

To convert a string to an int, you can do what is called **casting**. This is converting one type to another (They have to be compatible though.) Casting 'hello' to a number doesn't make sense and won't work.

Casting `'1'` to a number is possible by calling `int('1')` which will result in `1`

In your case you can cast all elements in you list by calling `a = [int(x) for x in a]`.

For more info on types see [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_datatypes.asp).
For information on list comprehensions (What I used to change your list) see [this article.](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension)